# Can I paint the inside frame of this window?

Tags: painting, paint, window-frame

Am I able to paint the metal part of the window? Also I wasn’t sure if I can paint the latches or are they removable?[image]

Comment: If you paint over the latches, you might cause them to stick in the position you painted them. At a minimum, you'll need a nice, sharp knife to cut the paint along the points where the latches move. Otherwise, when you move them, they'll just tear the paint wherever there are weak spots and that might not be along the edges where it would look nice.

Comment: This is just a bad idea. You may not like the color, but you'll like the result of a paint job even less. It'll make your modern low-maintenance window into a messy, fragile, old-looking thing. Use curtains to decorate instead.

Comment: Latches have screws and are removable.  I wouldn't paint the latches, but you can paint the window frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you *can* paint it. The odds that it will look as good, for as long, as the factory finish are vanishingly small, so you *may* also live to regret painting it.

The prominent screws suggest that the latches can be removed.

Comment: Should you _choose_ to repaint, be sure to do proper prep work, or you'll have wasted your time & money.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install wood trim around the window, which makes it look more like the wood-frame windows in the rest of the house. (The windows themselves have a matching wood surface trim so it's pretty convincing; I can post pics if there's interest.)